# Requery Listbox on secondary form when another form is closed

Tags: forms, ms-access

I have two forms, `frmOwnership` and `frmContactDetails`.  On `frmOwnership` you can click a button to open `frmContactDetails` to a specific record.

The issue I'm having is `frmContactDetails` is opened from several different sources, and doesn't designate (and can't really?) a form to open when it's closed.  And `frmOwnership` is not openable from `frmContactDetails`, meaning when you go to edit a record in the Contact Details, the Ownership form stays open.  However, I'm looking to refresh a control (`lstItem`) on `frmOwnership` when `frmContactDetails` is closed.  I tried to add a requery call (`lstItem.Requery`) to the Got_Focus procedure, but it's not refreshing.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is open `frmContactDetails` with `acDialog` (as a popup on top of whatever other form is opening it). Then whatever VBA code opens it on the original form only continues after `frmContactDetails` is closed and you can put your refresh there.

Comment: Something is wonky when I do that.  Using this code: ``DoCmd.OpenForm "frmContactDetails", View:=acNormal, WhereCondition:="[ID]" & Me.txtContactID, WindowMode:=acDialog``, nothing happens.

Comment: `"[ID]=" & Me.txtContactID` missing an equals there

Comment: Jesus, that's embarrassing.  It still doesn't refresh ``lstItem`` when ``frmContactDetails`` closes and ``frmDockRental`` regains "focus". (Put the requery in get focus.

Comment: Put the requery right after `DoCmd.OpenForm`. The code will halt after that until the called form is closed, then it will resume.